# How to extend method in C# subclass compared to Objective-C

Tags: c#, objective-c

I come from `Objective-C`. I'm learning `C#` now. How to achieve the `C#` equivalent of the following `Objective-C` call ?

```
- (void)doSomething
{
     [super doSomething]
     // do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class A
{
public virtual void doSomething() { Console.WriteLine("Class A"); }
}

class B : A
{
public override void doSomething()
{
base.doSomething();
Console.WriteLine("Class Y");
}
}

static void Main()
{
A b = new B();
b.doSomething();
Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: doSomething in the class A has to be virtual method?

Comment: Yes if you want to override it.
Try to get ride of the keyword `virtual` and compile the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `base` keyword:

```
public void doSomething(){
  base.doSomething();
}
```